# Android RegisterForActivity not returning Uri

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to open an image from the gallery by using the new activity launcher. I can launch and pick an image but there is nothing printing in the console which indicates that the image was not passed correctly?

```
    @Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstance) {
    ActivityResultLauncher<String> mGetContent = registerForActivityResult(new ActivityResultContracts.GetContent(),
            uri -> {
                // OnActivityResult
                System.out.println(uri);
                System.out.println("ACTIVITY");
                Log.d("Message", uri.toString());
            });

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle("Ladda upp bild").setItems(R.array.camera_or_gallery, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        /**
         * Dialog to show user to pick between camera or gallery
         * @item the index of the item that was chosen
         */
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            // If user chose camera
            if (item == 0) {
                checkCameraPermission();

            // If user chose gallery
            } else if (item == 1) {
                checkStoragePermission();
                mGetContent.launch("image/*");
            }
        }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```

Comment: Hi! I faced with a same Issue. Did you fix that?